# Get the number of columns between Column A and a certain Range in the sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I use this `VBA` to get the **first column** of `Range("C2:E4")`:

```
Sub Get_First_Column()
Sheet1.Range("C2:E4").Column
End Sub
```

In this case the result is `3`.

---

Now, I want to add the number of columns that is between the `Column A` and the `Range("C2:E4")`. 
In this case it would be `2` since `Column A` and `Column B` are between.
The result would be `5` in the end.

---

I could do this manually by just adding `+2`  behind the `VBA`. 
However, the `Range("C2:E4")` could also change to another range. Therefore, I am looking for a flexible solution.

Comment: `(Sheet1.Range("C2:E4").Column - Sheet1.Range("A1").Column)+Sheet1.Range("C2:E4").Column`

Comment: What is the desired result if `Range("G2:J8")`? `6+4=10` or `6+7=13`?

Comment: `With Range("G2:J8"):Debug.Print .Columns(.Columns.Count).Column: End With`

Comment: @Tim Williams: Then it would be an `XY problem`: OP is asking for my second choice, but actually wants my first choice (First Column not `Columns.Count`). My first choice and your solution are actually the last column.

Comment: @VBasic2008 - I agree the question is unclear.  It's possible the OP went the long way around to describe what they wanted.  Or that they want something else...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is the comment from [Scott Craner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851590/scott-craner):

```
Sub Get_First_Column()
(Sheet1.Range("C2:E4").Column - Sheet1.Range("A1").Column)+Sheet1.Range("C2:E4").Column
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
Sub Get_First_Column()

    Debug.Print 2 * Sheet1.Range("C2:E4").Column - 1

End Sub
```

if you're looking to a flexible solution then set your range and result separately, as below

```
Sub Get_First_Column()

Dim rng As Range
Dim x As Long

Set rng = Sheet1.Range("C2:E4")

    x = 2 * rng.Column - 1

    MsgBox x    'delete this line, for testing only

End Sub
```